# Set material to a fixed part of mesh in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, mesh

Let's say I have a 3DObject in three.js:

```js
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

This mesh is also dynamic, that means, user sets the size of it, which is dynamically set as the `scale` of the mesh.

```js
widthInput.subscribe(value => this.mesh.scale.x = +value); // just to get the idea
```

So, I know it's possible to set separate materials to the different sides of geometry. I'm also aware that it should be possible to set it on separate segments of that geometry's sides (if I'd had more).

The problem is that the user can set the width from the range 200 - 260, but I need a different material on the very right of the mesh with a fixed size of 10. I'm not really sure how would I do that without creating another geometry. Is there any way to set the material on the fixed part of the mesh? or is there any way to set the segments the way one of them will always have the fixed size? Thank you in advance.

To visualize the problem (white area needs to have a fixed width of 10 while the red area resizes)

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you shying away from creating a new geometry? If you apply different materials to different sides, you cause more draw calls and webgl calls to happen anyway. If you create two boxes you have a very high level user friendly interface. If you handle this on the geometry level, you add more complexity. How do you manage where the segment would be? Are you going to modify the vertices and update the mesh? This would go against your `scale.set()` interface.

Comment: @pailhead You're right, probably. I'm just starting off with the whole 3d world of javascript without much knowledge. I guess my problem with creating multiple geometries lays down in too many objects which I then need to update (positions and scales) when the user sets the width for example. I mean, I will probably create the second 3DObject, but as well as you.. Out of curiosity I was wondering if it's possible to achieve :)

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to set the material on the fixed part of the mesh?

As you've already mentioned there is a way to set different materials on different parts of the geometry. The problem here is defining what **fixed** means:

> or is there any way to set the segments the way one of them will always have the fixed size?

Yes. You'd have to modify the geometry yourself. Reach into say `g.attributes.position.array` and modify the vertices that make the segment. It's lower level and different than the scene graph.

There may not be a good reason for wanting to keep everything in the same geometry. It would make sense if you used vertex colors for example to paint the different segments, and perhaps animated the extrusion in GLSL rather than with `scale.set()`. But since you want to apply different materials and are not writing GLSL, you will end up with multiple draw calls anyway.

You actually can save a bit of memory by storing just the simple cube and referencing it twice, than storing extra vertices and faces. So what you're trying to do is more likely going to consume more memory, and have the same amount of render overhead. In which case, doing everything with the scene graph, with two meshes and **one geometry** (you dont need to duplicate the box, you only need two **nodes**) should be as performant, and much easier to work with.

Comment: Thank you, well explained. I will use multiple objects which I'd group for easier scaleability and positioning. Would that be a good approach?

Comment: exactly, no premature optimization :) The scene graph (`Mesh`) is friendly and convenient. You can do simple math on `position.set()` and `scale.set()`. If you end up having thousands of these, then it would require a revisit, but assigning multiple materials to the same geometry actually wouldn't be a valid path in this case. But that's material for a different question

Comment: If you have multiples of these, each one would have to have unique geometry in order for you to modify their vertices independently. This wouldn't be a good approach either. But you would merge the two draw calls (fixed part and dynamic part). If you make a single geometry and assign some vertex attributes to it. Simple example - vertex colors, you can assign red to the dynamic part and blue to the fixed. In the shader you'd pass your own scale uniform that stretches the red vertices and only offsets the blue. You could then instance this for further optimization.

Comment: Well in my case I'm just creating a "wardrobe creating studio", so I might have around 40-50 meshes all together with a floor and maybe some "room-space simulation" (2-3 walls -> meshes). Although, I create each of them out of it's own geometry, I didn't realize any low performance at all for now.

Comment: Thanks once again for taking a time for explanation. Now I see, it's not really worth a while for me to put those materials on the one geometry.